# EF6 using multiples DbContext - (The entity type EntityName is not part of the model for the current context)

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an application that we have some modules. We have for example FinancialModule and EmployeeModule.

I have an Core project that I created an abstract class called DefaultDbContext that inherits from DbContext and I have an abstract method called ModelCreating that all ConcreteClass (EFFinacialContext and EFEmployeeContext) should implement it to add mapping class.

My problem is that, I have an application with these modules and receiving this message "The entity type EntityName is not part of the model for the current context."

I have each module in running in another application and everything is okay, so,something is wrong when running together.

Who had the same problem using applications with multiples db context?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Heres your problem

```
public class Context1 : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Entity1> E1{get;set;}
}

public class Context2 : DbContext
{
    public IDbSet<Entity2> E2{get;set;}
}

public class Entity1
{
    //some stuff
}

public class Entity2
{
    //some stuff
    public Entity1 E1 {get;set;} //you arent allowed this as its not in your current dbcontext
}
```

Comment: he cant ref an entity which is attached to his other context from an entity inside his current context

Comment: I think you should look at your example again, more closely.